# scroll clicked to the center of the screen in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

I have UIScrollView with label. I am getting touch events coordinates. When user is clicking on screen i am storing the click coordinates in variable, then i want to scroll the view (using something like [myScrollView setContentOffset]) in such a way so the y coordinate of the clicked point will become a center of my view, so when you clicking on some text it will autoscroll to the center of the screen. I am not sure how to workout the math of this...

Any help highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UIScrollView *aScrollView;      
CGPoint touchPoint;
[aScrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(touchPoint.x - roundf(aScrollView.frame.size.width/2.),
                                                  touchPoint.y - roundf(aScrollView.frame.size.height/2.), 
                                                  aScrollView.frame.size.width, 
                                                  aScrollView.frame.size.height)  
                                                  animated:YES];
```

Should work.

Comment: thanks Kai, it works. There is still issue though - first time you click on some text it will scroll to the center, which is what i wanted. But if you click it again (while it stays at the center of the screen) it will scroll back to previous position...

Comment: Sounds strange. Maybe you don't grab/store the touch point the right way. Post some code (Maybe in another question).

Comment: @KaiHuppmann this code is working perfect. Thank you. But can you help  me. This is not working when the scrollview is zoomed. Can you help me in applying the zoomscale ratio here?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is very similar, but I'm using scale and I want to center a view, not a touch point. So I need to calculate the center point first.

My final code:

```
UIView *view; //View to center
UIScrollView *scrollView; //scroll view

CGPoint point = CGPointMake(view.frame.origin.x + view.frame.size.width / 2, 
                            view.frame.origin.y + view.frame.size.height / 2);

CGRect rectToZoom = CGRectMake(point.x * scrollView.zoomScale - roundf(scrollView.frame.size.width /2.),
                               point.y * scrollView.zoomScale - roundf(scrollView.frame.size.height /2.),
                               scrollView.frame.size.width,
                               scrollView.frame.size.height);

[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:rectToZoom animated:YES];
```